# Three js Trackball controls - manual rotation

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm having problems with trackballControls in three.js.  I'd like to rotate and position the camera manually. Here's the test function.

```
function rotateTest(){
    console.log(camera.rotation) // THREE.Euler {_x: 0, _y: 0.7853981462831776, _z: 0, _order: "XYZ", onChangeCallback: function…}

    camera.rotateZ(1);
    console.log(camera.rotation) // THREE.Euler {_x: 7.850462316470535e-17, _y: 0.7853981462831774, _z: 1, _order: "XYZ", onChangeCallback: function…} 
}
```

The objects rotation appears to be altered but no change is actually seen. Could someone please help me out.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

you can first create a cube and focus at it.

when you move the cube and the camera can be rotated

```
cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(10,10,10), new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x123876}));
camera.lookAt(cube);
//rotate: use cube.position.x++;
//camera: use camera.position.x++;
```

and the trackBall can still be used.
if you want some camera tilt effect, watch this threejs example.

http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_particles_billboards